# Graphics2D drawString produces nonsense characters after Java 6

Tags: java, graphics2d

While migrating an older application to a newer server with Java 8, this problem came up: words in an image that look fine with Java 6 became nonsense characters in Java 7 and 8.

Here is my test code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PicTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String testNum = args[0];
        String fileName = "image"+testNum+".jpg";
        String testText = "Test "+testNum;

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200,200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.drawString(testText, 10, 20);
        File outputfile = new File(fileName);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

When I run this with Java 6...

```
$ /usr/local/java/java6/bin/javac test/PicTest.java
$ /usr/local/java/java6/bin/java test/PicTest 4
```

... here is the (expected, normal) output image:
[test image 4 using Java 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZNhk.jpg)

And when I run this with Java 7...

```
$ /usr/local/java/java7_17/bin/javac test/PicTest.java
$ /usr/local/java/java7_17/bin/java test/PicTest 5
```

... here is the output image (with nonsense chars):
[test image 5 using Java 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrMdc.jpg)

The image I get using Java 8 is the same as Java 7.

By Java 6 I mean jdk1.6.0_34
By Java 7 I mean jdk1.7.0_17

Should I be using different libraries or setting things up differently to make this work with more recent versions of Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java 6 "Serif" is a logical font. Physical fonts were introduced at some point, and it seems you actually have a physical font by the name of "Serif" on your system. Use a different, physical, font family. Or "Sans-Serif" for the moment.

In java one can iterate through all [GrahicsEnvironment's fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html):

```
GraphicsEnvironment genv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
for (String fontName : getAvailableFontFamilyNames()) {
    System.out.println(fontName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this put me on the right track.  As it turned out, my test program produced acceptable output (no "nonsense" chars) on my Mac, but on the linux system where this runs, that is where the problem is.  So that also points to fonts being the issue.  Of 20 fonts in the environment, 14 produced garbage and 6 were good (neither Serif, SansSerif did).  I changed my code to cycle through each font and produce output.